# How to prove reduction from decision to seach LWE?

Tags: lwe

I am new to cryptography, and trying to understand the concepts of LWE (learning with errors) formally. I will state my understanding of the definitions, which might be incorrect.

### Definitions According to My Understanding

Let $R$ be a finite unital commutative ring equipped with a probability $\mu$ (whose $\sigma$-algebra is discrete). $R$ is said to satisfy the **worst-case search LWE assumption** if for all polynomial $n$ and all polynomial-time randomized algorithm $S$, the map
\begin{equation}
    m\mapsto \min_{s\in R^m} p(m,s)\text{,}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    p(m,s) = \Pr\{(A,e)\in R^{m\times n(m)} \times R^{n(m)}: S (-sA+e,A)=s\}\text{,}
\end{equation}
is negligible. In the above equation, $A$ is sampled from the uniform probability, and $e$ is sampled from the product probability $\mu^{n(m)}$.

$R$ is said to satisfy the **worst-case decision LWE assumption** if for all polynomial $n$ and all polynomial-time randomized algorithm $D$, the map
\begin{equation}
    m\mapsto \min_{s\in R^m} |p_1(m,s)-p_2(m)|\text{,}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        p_1(m,s) &= \Pr\{(A,e)\in R^{m\times n(m)}\times R^{n(m)}: D (-sA+e,A)=1\},\\
        p_2(m) &= \Pr\{(b,A)\in R^{n(m)}\times R^{m\times n(m)}\times: D (b,A)=1\}\text{,}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
is negligible. In the above equation, $A$ and $b$ are sampled from the uniform probabilities, and $e$ is sampled from the product probability $\mu^{n(m)}$.

### Question

I proved that if $R$ is a finite field equipped with a probability $\mu$ (whose $\sigma$-algebra is discrete) and if $R$ satisfies the worst-case search LWE assumption, then $R$ also satisfies the worst-case decision LWE assumption. But how does one prove the converse? All literature I have seen so far just say that it is trivial, but I could not prove it. More explicitly, I need a proof of the following statement:

If $R$ is a finite unital commutative ring equipped with a probability $\mu$ (whose $\sigma$-algebra is discrete) and if $R$ satisfies the worst-case decision LWE assumption, then $R$ also satisfies the worst-case search LWE assumption.

### My Attempt

Assume that $R$ satisfies the worst-case decision LWE assumption. Let $n$ be a polynomial and let $S$ be a polynomial-time randomized algorithm (whose inputs are elements in $R^{n(m)}\times R^{m\times n(m)}$ and whose outputs are elements in $R^m$). We need to show that the map
\begin{equation}
    m\mapsto \min_{s\in R^m} p(m,s)\text{,}
\end{equation}
where $p(m,s)$ is defined above, is negligible. Given an input $(b,A)\in R^{n(m)}\times R^{m\times n(m)}$ where $b=-sA+e$, $S$ will return some guess $g\in R^m$ that might or might not equal $s$. One can compute $b+gA$ and denote it by $e'$. If $g=s$, then $e'=e$. If $g\neq s$, then $e'=e$ might or might not hold. I do not know what to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are quite close to the correct answer, I won't give you the right answer, but instead will give you a qualitative description of the the final step you need to do.

Depending on the precise error distribution one chooses $e$ from, the LWE distribution $(A, sA + e)$ can be either:

1. exactly the uniform distribution (say if $e$ is uniformly random)
2. computationally distinguishable from uniform (say if $e$ is supported on $\{0\}$), or
3. (thought to be) computationally indistinguishable from uniform (if $e$ is "bounded" --- you can explicitly view this to mean having i.i.d. Gaussian coordinates of parameter $\approx n$).

These three cases are useful to keep in mind when considering the random variable $(A, sA+e)$.
Note that (for fixed $A$) the map $s\mapsto sA$ defines a lattice.
The decisional LWE problem is (roughly) about detecting this lattice structure. For example

1. in the first case, $sA+e$ is uniform over $R$, e.g. the error $e$ "washes out" any of the lattice structure (information theoretically),
2. in the second case $sA$ is exactly a point in the lattice, and there exist efficient ways to test membership of some candidate point $b = sA$ in the lattice in this case, and
3. in the third case, $sA$ is a perturbed point of the lattice, and it is plausibly hard to decide you are "close" to the lattice.

All of this is to say that your question has *very* different answers depending on the precise characteristics of the error distribution, so the error distribution has to factor into your answer somehow.
For a hint how it will, you say

> If $g\neq s$, then $e′=e$ might or might not hold. I do not know what to do now.

When $g\neq s$, then $b + gA =(g-s)A+e$. Roughly speaking, what you do next is argue that it is very unlikely for $(g-s)A+e$ to be drawn from the error distribution. This is because

1. the error distribution is concentrated around zero (or perhaps even bounded), e.g. any element of the error distribution will have $|e|$ "small", and
2. when $g\neq s$, $(g-s)A$ will be greater than $\lambda_1(\mathcal{L}(A))$, the shortest vector of the lattice $\mathcal{L}(A)$. For random $A$, this is typically "large".

It should seem plausible that you can quantitatively parameterize things such that, using quantitative versions of the above two statements, that it is unlikely that $g\neq s$>